# Minimum of convex sum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convex-optimization

Let $X$ be a random vector distributed uniformly over the centered sphere of radius 2 in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $Y$ be a random vector distributed uniformly over the centered sphere of radius 1 in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Define $Z$ to be the minimum norm of a convex sum, i.e.
$$
Z := \min_{\alpha + \beta = 1, \alpha, \beta \geq 0} \|\alpha X + \beta Y \|_2
$$
What is the expectation of $Z$?  My intuition is that when $X$ and $Y$ are pointed in roughly the same direction then all the weight should be on the smaller vector, but for more general layouts it's not clear to me.

Comment: Just draw the triangle and look at it for a minute. Then observe that everything depends only on the angle $\theta$ between $X$ and $Y$ and you know its distribution. Then set up the integral (it will be something like $c\int\frac{\sin^n\theta}{\sqrt{5-4\cos\theta}}\,d\theta$ in the interesting part of $[0,\pi]$) and enjoy computing it (the antiderivative is elementary for at least odd $n$).

Comment: Hi @fedja could you explain in a little more detail.  What triangle are you talking about?